# Using weblate with WordPress to create a multi-lingual website

Tags: wordpress, weblate

Can weblate be used with a Wordpress site to be translated?

Is there a way to integrate it easily where 'approved' strings are copied to the website and does it work well with the existing multi-language plug-ins out there?

Comment: This is possible https://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress

please do simple google before ask aquestion

Comment: Thank you miuranga. This question is specifically about the integration with the software Weblate. Not about setting up a multi-language wordpress website.

Comment: @Miuranga The WordPress page doesn't mention any kind of open collaborative tool. That was a bit to quick to pull the "just search on the web"